# Invalid Syntax in keras model.add Convolutional layers

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, activation-function

I am trying to build a VGG16 model but came across the

> invalid syntax error

while compiling it. Error is in the activation function of the below line.

```
 model.add(Convolution2D((64,3,3,activation='relu')))
```

However, if I change the code as below, its working fine.

```
    model.add(Convolution2D((64,3,3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
```

I have seen many related questions and the answers say that it is due to the missing parenthesis in the above line of code, but I checked the parenthesis and they are fine. Why is the code giving me issues when i mention ***activation*** parameter in Convolution2D layer. I checked the [documentation](http://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.2.2/layers/convolutional/) and it is supposed to accept the parameter. What am I missing here.

Here is the detailed code

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Flatten,Dense,Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import cv2, numpy as np

def VGG16(weights_path=none):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1),input=(3,224,224)))
        model.add(Convolution2D(64,3,3,activation='relu'))
        model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
        model.add(Convolution2D(64,3,3,activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2),strides=(2,2)))
```

Comment: You have put **extra** parentheses for instantiating `Conv2D` layer. Remove one of the parenthesis right after `Conv2D` and one from the end of the line and it should work.

Comment: Your detailed code does not match with your snippet, also please add the full traceback.

Comment: @today, I have removed that extra parentheses but I still see the same issue.

Comment: @Sree As Matias mentioned the code snippet at the end does not match the lines of code at the beginning of your question. Could you please write a final version and also include a full traceback of the error in that final version?